# Naming each item in a list which is a value of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary for which key is a normal string and value is a tuple for which example is shown below:

```
'Europe':(Germany, France, Italy)
'Asia':(India, China, Malaysia)
```

I want to display the dictionary items like this:

```
'Europe':(RandomStringA:Germany, RandomStringB:France, RandomStringC:Italy)  
'Asia':(RandomStringA:India, RandomStringB:China, RandomStringC:Malaysia)
```

I tried the code below:

```
for k, v in dict.iteritems()  
    print k, "Country1":v[0], "Country2":v[1], "Country3":v[2]
```

But this does not seem to work. Is there a way to tag items in a tuple like that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use actual Python to show your data structures - your current examples don't make sense.

Comment: You say value is a list, but you show value as a tuple.  Which is it?

Comment: Why does this nice say `RandomStringA` etc... ?

Comment: If you change your `print` line to `print repr(k), ":(Country1:"+v[0]+ ", Country2:"+v[1]+ ", Country3:"+v[2]`, then your solution would also work, but only if all tuples are of length 3. And this way you wouldn't need the use of `join`, `enumerate`, `format`,...

Comment: Sorry, your update doesn't clarify things. What does `"RadomStringX"` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to print that:

```
for k, v in dct.iteritems():
    print repr(k)+ ":(" + ", ".join("Country{}:{}".format(i,c) for i,c in enumerate(v, start=1)) + ")"
```

Output:

```
'Europe':(Country1:Germany, Country2:France, Country3:Italy)
'Asia':(Country1:India, Country2:China, Country3:Malaysia)
```

Note: I'm abusing the function of `repr()` to get the quotes in there. You could just as well do `"'" + str(k) + "'"`.

The reason why your code doesn't work is your use of `:` outside of a dictionary initialization or comprehension. That is, you can do `d = {'a':'b'}` but you can't do `print 'a':'b'`. Also, you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name, because it is a keyword.

My solution will work for tuples which have more (or even less) than 3 elements in them, too.

Comment: I am very very sorry for the confusion. I edited the post again.

Comment: @JustinCarrey You're going to have to elaborate on what `"RandomStringA"`. `"RandomStringB"`, etc. mean. Do you want to have anything in place of `"Country"`? Do you want to count alphabetically, not numerically?

Answer (score 0):

```
mainDict = {"Europe": ("Germany", "France", "Italy"),
  "Asia": ("India", "China", "Malaysia")
}

for item in mainDict:
    print "%s:(%s)" % (item, ", ".join(["Country%s:%s" % (r+1, y) for r, y in enumerate(mainDict[item])]))
```

Print out:

```
Europe:(['Country1:Germany', 'Country2:France', 'Country3:Italy'])
Asia:(['Country1:India', 'Country2:China', 'Country3:Malaysia'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that I know of that will do it, but it's pretty simple to do what you want:

```
countries = {
    'Europe': ('Germany', 'France', 'Italy'),
    'Asia': ('India', 'China', 'Malaysia'),
}

for k, v in countries.iteritems():
    print k+':', tuple(map(lambda c: 'Country%d:%s' % c, enumerate(v, start=1)))
```

Output:

```
Europe: ('Country1:Germany', 'Country2:France', 'Country3:Italy')
Asia: ('Country1:India', 'Country2:China', 'Country3:Malaysia')
```

Comment: Clever lambda... for a second, I thought you had forgotten an argument. That can be written as `lambda (i, c): 'Country%d:%s' % i, c` right? (Just for my clarification.)

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yes, that would work, too, as well as be more explicit. Good point.

Comment: I am very very sorry for the confusion. I edited the post again.